# Single word for one who is a great fan of movies?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word to denote **a person who watches more movies** in free time?

Single word with meaning similar to "Movie Freak"?

Answer (score 34):

The word is [*cinephile*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinephilia) or *cinemaphile*:

> Cinephilia is the term used to refer to a passionate interest in cinema, film theory and film criticism. The term is a portmanteau of the words cinema and philia, one of the four ancient Greek words for love.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinephilia) A person with a passionate interest in cinema is called a cinephile. [Wikipedia]

From the same article:

> In the 1993 film Benny & Joon, actor Johnny Depp portrays Sam, a *cinemaphile* man who falls in love with a mentally ill woman named Joon (Mary Stuart Masterson).

Comment: Also, [cineast/cineaste](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cineast) ... The WP page clarifies that while it is synonymous with cinephile in English, _in French_, "the term refers to a cinephile who is also a filmmaker".

Answer (score 10):

*Film Buff* is less derogatory than *Movie Freak*, but it is 2 words. *Cinephile* meets your criteria.

Answer (score 6):

An [*aficionado*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/aficionado) is a person who is very knowledgeable and enthusiastic about an activity, subject, or pastime. Unless it's clear from the context that the person is interested in movies, you would need to modify it with another word: *movie aficionado* or *film aficionado.* But it doesn't have the negative connotation of *freak*.